# Verb forms for "any" and "none" — have or has?

Tags: prepositions, subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

> That car is way better than any car any of us **have/has** ever driven.
>
> None of us **know/knows** which direction Ron's house is **(in)**.

I have two questions here.

1. In both the cases, are we to use the *singular* verb, or the *plural*?
2. In the end of the second sentence, is using the *preposition* where it's been used, necessary? Would it be okay if it had no prepositions in it?

Comment: Merriam-Webster has a good explaination for this. Watch it https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Kte0VHe1aUI

Comment: Apparently, *any* is always singular.

Comment: What about the preposition at the end of the second sentence? 
Would the sentence be okay without it? @user178049

Comment: @user178049 Nope.  *Any* is not always singular, but that's a myth of long standing.

Answer (score 8):

The following extract from [Dictionary.com](http://blog.dictionary.com/none/) suggests that both the singular and the plural verb form are correct after "none". Usage depends on the emphasis that you want to give to "none" as either a singular  or a plural subject. Also evidence from [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=none%20of%20us%20know%2Cnone%20of%20us%20knows&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20us%20know%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnone%20of%20us%20knows%3B%2Cc0) shows both usages are common.

> - ***None means ‘not one’ or ‘not any’ and it may take either a singular or plural verb.***
> - Writers are more or less free to decide which meaning is appropriate in their context. ***This grammatical construction, which is based on sense rather than form, is called notional agreement or notional concord, and is very common.***
> - ***So, consider none as singular when you want to emphasize a single entity in a group, but consider none to be plural when you want to emphasize more than one.***

Examples are:

> - *None of the books is/are worth reading. / None of us is/are going to the banquet. However, when none means ‘no amount’ or ‘no part’, it must be singular:None of the debris has been cleared away. / None of the forest is deciduous. So, if your meaning is ‘none of them’, treat the word as plural; if it is ‘none of it’, treat it as singular.*

Similarly ***[any of](http://www.antimoon.com/forum/2004/3892.htm)*** can take  both constructions according to the meaning conveyed:

> - When used as a pronoun, "any" can take either a singular or plural verb, depending on how it is construed: Any of these books is suitable (that is, any one). But are any (that is, some) of them available?

Answer (score 2):

### Concerning None have/None has

["none"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/none) has been used with both singular and plural verbs since the 9th century.

**Fact:** Only when *none* is clearly intended to mean “not one” or “not any” is it followed by a singular verb in all other cases it is plural.

> One special problem occurs with the word none, which has its origin in
>   the phrase not one. Because of that original meaning, many writers
>   insist that none always be singular, as not one clearly is. However, a
>   more accurate way to assess its meaning is to recognize none as the
>   negative, or opposite, of all and to treat it in the same way, with
>   its number determined by the number of the modifier.

Examples from [Martha Kolln, Rhetorical Grammar](https://www.englishrules.com/writing/2005/none-singular-or-plural/):

- All of the cake *was* left.
- None of the cake *was* left.

  ---
- All of the cookies *were* left.
- None of the cookies *were* left.

> Advice given by [Richard Lederer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Lederer) and [Richard Dowis](http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/80792.Richard_Dowis) is typical:
>   “Consider *none* as *singular* when you want to emphasize a *single entity
>   in a group*. Consider it *plural* when you want to emphasize *more than
>   one*”

- None of us is going to the party.
- None of us are going to the party.

> When none is followed by a mass noun (a noun that cannot be counted or
>   made plural) it takes a singular verb. [Source](http://www.onlinegrammar.com.au/top-10-grammar-myths-none-always-takes-a-singular-verb/).

- None of the wine was drunk. (wine = mass noun)

> [Note](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/singular-vs-plural/none-were-vs-none-was/): Apparently, the SAT testing service considers none as a singular
>   word only. However, according to Merriam Webster’s Dictionary of
>   English Usage, “Clearly none has been both singular and plural since
>   Old English and still is. The notion that it is singular only is a
>   myth of unknown origin that appears to have arisen in the 19th
>   century. If in context it seems like a singular to you, use a singular
>   verb; if it seems like a plural, use a plural verb. Both are
>   acceptable beyond serious criticism” (p. 664)

### Concerning Any have/Any has

[First of all](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/any): We use *any of* to refer to a part of a whole:

- Are any of you going to the meeting?
- I couldn’t answer any of these questions.
- I listen to Abba but I’ve never bought any of their music.

> We use any with of before articles (a/an, the), demonstratives (this,
>   these), pronouns (you, us) or possessives (his, their). Any is very
>   often used with uncountable and plural nouns. It can have the same
>   kind of meaning as the indefinite article a/an has with singular
>   countable nouns. [Source](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00294.html)

---

> "When used as a pronoun, any can take either a singular or plural
>   verb, depending on how it is construed: Any of these books is suitable
>   (that is, any one). But are any (that is, some) of them available?

- Have any of my suggestions helped you? - *Not just one, maybe two or three suggestions have helped you.*
- Has any of my suggestions helped you? - *Only one out of many.*

> Conjugating “to do” demonstrates that “does” is used with a (third
>   person) singular object. Now, since “Do any here object?” sounds
>   right, but “Does any here object?” doesn’t suggests that “any” regards
>   a plurality. Also, the fact that the word “anyONE” exists at all
>   suggests that “any” normally refers to a plurality. [Source](https://www.englishforums.com/English/IfAnyOfYouIsAreOffended/wrrpq/post.htm)

### Concerning Prepositions at the end of a sentence

[BBC states](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1535_questionanswer/page52.shtml): In written English, we try to avoid putting the preposition at the end of the sentence. We can say “That’s the film I’m interested in.” “That’s the university which I studied at.” “That’s a song I’ve heard of.” But when were writing formal English, we try to take that preposition and put it into the middle of the sentence. This is where we need to use the relative pronoun which – “That’s the university I studied at.” “That’s the university at which I studied.” “That’s the film I’m interested in.” “That’s the film in which I’m interested.”

But there are cases when if you place the preposition in the middle of the sentence it will either be awkward of too formal to use (unless that is the result you wish to get).

- Who did you give your number to? - Okay
- To whom did you give your number?  - Very formal

  ---
- What does she look like? - Okay
- Like what does she look? - Awkward

  ---
- Can you tell me what you are looking for? - Okay
- Can you tell me for what you are looking?  Awkward

More examples can be found [here](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/preps-placement.html).