# "Do" or "Does" with "any of X"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, questions, subject-verb-agreement, auxiliary-verbs

Which is correct:

> 1. Do any of the ideas interest you?

> 2. Does any of the ideas interest you?

In one textbook, it gives 2 as an example sentence; however, in another one, I read something similar but it uses "do"-- "Do any of you have cars?"  I am confused.

Comment: This might be helpful as well [Which is the correct phrasing: Do any or Does any?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/149939/9161) I'm not sure it is an exact duplicate because it doesn't address "Do any of". It just talks about "Do any".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verb forms for "any" and "none" — have or has?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/108007/verb-forms-for-any-and-none-have-or-has)

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible depending on the situation.

If there are half a dozen ideas in question and the respondent is able to choose several of them, the question should be:

**Do any of the ideas interest you?**

But if the respondent has to choose only one idea from those being presented, the question might well be:

**Does any (one) of the ideas interest you?**

In most cases, the likely response would be to use the plural **do**.

But it depends on the context. Grammatically, both are correct.